# postgresql two NOT LIKE clauses returning wrong results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 88 codes. I am writing a simple select statement that does not select the codes that start with `10` or `18`

```
select distinct pcl_mun from exemptions.modiv_parcels_2015 
where (pcl_mun NOT LIKE '10%') or (pcl_mun NOT LIKE '18%')
order by pcl_mun
```

one would assume this would work but it returns ALL the results

```
"0233"
"0242"
"1001"
"1002"
"1003"
"1004"
"1005"
"1006"
"1012"
"1013"
"1014"
"1015"
"1018"
"1019"
"1020"
"1024"
"1025"
"1401"
"1402"
"1403"
"1406"
"1407"
"1408"
"1409"
"1412"
"1413"
"1414"
"1415"
"1418"
"1419"
"1420"
"1421"
"1422"
"1423"
"1424"
"1425"
"1426"
"1427"
"1428"
"1429"
"1431"
"1432"
"1433"
"1434"
"1435"
"1436"
"1437"
"1438"
"1439"
"1601"
"1609"
"1611"
"1613"
"1615"
"1801"
"1802"
"1803"
"1807"
"1815"
"1904"
"1906"
"1908"
"1909"
"1911"
"1912"
"1916"
"1918"
"1919"
"1922"
"2101"
"2102"
"2103"
"2105"
"2106"
"2107"
"2108"
"2110"
"2111"
"2112"
"2114"
"2115"
"2116"
"2117"
"2119"
"2120"
"2121"
"2122"
"2123"
```

If i just run each one of those like clauses by themselves they return the correct results. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You probably want an `and` here. Or have it as `NOT ((pcl_mun LIKE '10%') or (pcl_mun LIKE '18%'))`.

Comment: @Marth how would an `AND` make any sense in this scenario?

Comment: `10xx` fails first "NOT LIKE", but matches second one, oppositely does `18xx`. At least one condition is always true (unless value is NULL), thus or-ing them gives true as well.

Comment: @AlexSalauyou that explanation clicked, makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When combining `NOT LIKE` then `AND` should be used instead of `OR`

```
select distinct pcl_mun 
from exemptions.modiv_parcels_2015 
where pcl_mun NOT LIKE '10%' 
  AND pcl_mun NOT LIKE '18%'
order by pcl_mun
```

It's a logical thing that can confuse sometimes.

Simplified examples:

```
('18' NOT LIKE '10%') OR ('18' NOT LIKE '18%')  --> true OR false --> true
('18' NOT LIKE '10%') AND ('18' NOT LIKE '18%')  --> true AND false --> FALSE

('14' NOT LIKE '10%') OR ('14' NOT LIKE '18%')  --> true OR true --> TRUE
('14' NOT LIKE '10%') AND ('14' NOT LIKE '18%')  --> true AND true --> TRUE
```

Because it's different when negating a combination of `LIKE`'s.
Then `OR` should be used instead.

```
NOT ('18' LIKE '10%' OR '18' LIKE '18%')  --> NOT(false OR true) --> FALSE
NOT ('18' LIKE '10%' AND '18' LIKE '18%')  --> NOT(false AND true) --> true

NOT ('14' LIKE '10%' OR '14' LIKE '18%')  --> NOT(false OR false) --> TRUE
NOT ('14' LIKE '10%' AND '14' LIKE '18%')  --> NOT(false AND false) --> TRUE
```